# Invalid URL key error while upload through import .csv

Tags: magento-2.3

I'm using magento 2.3.1 i have 2000 products in csv format when i import products through System->Import->Add/Update myproducts.csv output as general exception raised Invalid url key

I remove url key column still error raised and clear all cache, first 25 records also raised same problem